# How do I inspect an object going through a model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

If I put

```
binding.pry
```

inside a model to see the instance going through the validation... how do I see the attributes inputted by the forms?

what is the object called, and how can I view the attributes submitted by the form?

Comment: _how do I see the attributes inputted by the forms_, that must be available in the controller, not the model.

Comment: ... right, the model and the validations only kick in if object.save?

Comment: ... well, that solved my problem but didn't answer my question I guess.   thanks!

Comment: You can inspect the model before being saved but that won't give you the data from the params, just the one passed to instantiate the new object.

Comment: if you binding.pry inside a model, is there anything you can type to bring up the object being saved?   object_id brings up the Class id (?)

Comment: You can put a binding.pry right in a before_save callback, once there `self` is the same object and you can invoke any of its methods.